# removing __all__ from django form.errors

Tags: python, django

i want to render errors in each field
and remove the **all** from errors

```
             {% csrf_token %}
                {% if  form.errors %}
                    <p><strong>{{form.errors}}</strong></p>
                {% endif %}
                <label>{{form.username.label}}</label>
                {% render_field form.username class+='form-control border' %}

                <br>
                 <label>{{form.password.label}}</label>
                {% render_field form.password class+='form-control border' %}

                <br>
             <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
                <p>don't have an account <a href="">Register</a> </p>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can loop for each field in your form and put an if statement to check if there is an errors  in your form or you can do it manually for each field

```
    {% if form.username.errors %}
          {{form.username.errors}}
           {#to do error handling #}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you want to enter errors for each field , if so you can check this out in the docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields